# Is it possible to remember toolbars positions on toolbartray in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, position, toolbar

I have few toolbars:

```
<ToolBarTray>
    <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="1">...</ToolBar>
    <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="2">...</ToolBar>
    <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="3">...</ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```

and I'm wondering if I can save somehow new positions of toolbar if user has changed them?

For example user has changed position of first and second and has closed app. After running, first is first and second is second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that a default control won't go so far as to persist its own settings and that in order to achieve this you would need to hook into the relevant events (assuming there are some) and do some work to serialize the current state of the toolbar to a settings file that you can read across loads to initalise the control back to that state.

Comment: I'd be highly surprised if so - the most you should hope for is the control exposing a way of easily serializing the state for you to then write, but I doubt this, too.

Comment: there might be some third party tools which support settings also.